# XPath for parent element with certain descendant element, regardless of depth

Tags: xml, xpath

I have such XMLs

**Case 1**

```
<A>
   <B>
     <TAB name="tab1a">
      <FIELD name="myField">
      </FIELD>
     </TAB>
  </B>
</A>
```

**Case 2**

```
<A>
  <B>
    <TAB name="tab1b">
     <C>
      <D>
       <FIELD name="myField">
       </FIELD>
      </D>
     </C>
    </TAB>
  </B>
</A>
```

**Case 3**

```
<A>
  <TAB name="tab1c">
     <B>
       <C>
         <D>
           <FIELD name="myField">
           </FIELD>
          </D>
        </C>
      </B>
   </TAB>
</A>
```

I need to get name of `TAB` containing a `FIELD` named `myField`.

I've tried so far

```
//Tab[Field[@name="myField"]]/@name
```

and

```
//Field[@name="myField"]/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/@name.
```

but I would like do in in one universal query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//TAB[.//FIELD/@name='myField']/@name
```

will return the `@name` values of the `TAB` elements having a descendent `FIELD` element with `@name` of `"myField"`.  It will work for each of your cases individually, as requested.

If you were to wrap all of your cases in a single root element, it will return all of the `TAB/@name` values,

```
tab1a
tab1b
tab1c
```

because they all contain qualifying `FIELD` descendants.